# React input value is not changing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My input Tag is here:

```
<Input
   value={isNaN(currentCount) ? '' : currentCount}
   onKeyUp={(e) => {
      onKeyup(e);
      if (e.key === 'Enter') {}
   }}
   onChange={(e) => {
      handleChange(e);
   }}
/>
```

onKeyUp is working, but onChange is not working now.

I found that the value of the input tag does not change when I enter a value in the textbox.

Please let me know if you have had the same problem as me or know how to fix it.

Comment: Did you try checking(console.log) the value of `e.key`? Side note: Wrap your input inside a form so that most of accessibility controls are taken care of.

Comment: And `handleChange` does what?

Comment: Please share the handleChange function of your code.

Comment: Give the proper code with all functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a state and set your input value in it like below:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('')

const onChange = (event) => {
   setValue(event.target.value)
}

return (
<Input
   value={value}
   onKeyUp={(e) => {
      onKeyup(e);
      if (e.key === 'Enter') {}
   }}
   onChange={handleChange}
/>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [ currentCount, setCurrentCount] = useState('');
    
const handleChange = (e) => {
   setCurrentCount( e.target.value || '');
}

return (
  <input type="text" value={ isNaN(currentCount) ? '' : currentCount } onChange={ (e) =>  handleChange(e) }/>
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).